# Apply various graphs in multiple Excel sheets (acording to the number rows in each sheet)

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a pivot chart showing main cities as "filter" (80 in total) and certain performance numbers as "sum of values". In an Excel file, I have 26 sheets corresponding to the countries of those cities, and in every sheet a table with the list of cities (for some countries it could be 1 row (1 city), 5 rows or whatever..)

In each country sheet, I´m supposed to show that table (already done) together with a graph for each row of the table performance (again, it could be 1, 5 or whatever).

I thought that the easiest way to perform it was to paste the pivot chart in every sheet and then select automatically every row with the city name and apply it to the filter of the pivot.

By far, that´s the code I wrote:

```
Sub PastPivot() 
    Dim sht As Worksheet
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
        ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
    For Each sht In Worksheets
        sht.Range("a16").PasteSpecial
    Next
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

but I have several issues:

1. It pump up "error 5" when running the code
2. I´m not sure on how to write the code for it to perform in each sheet as many charts as rows (and how to determine the location of the chart considering that I won´t have the same number of charts on each sheet).

Maybe the solution is to use another type of graph and not a pivot one.

Any advice on how to perform it?